# Terminology for the sidewall of a mezzanine floor

Tags: terminology

For a mezzanine, stage or other flooring with an exposed sidewall, what is the proper construction or architectural term for that sidewall?

For example, here we see a mezzanine:

[image]

The red circle shows the exposed sidewall, which is here paneled in hardwood. What is the term for this sidewall?

Answer (score 1):

Some more research led me to the answer: it is called the *fascia*. The gallery is supported by beams called *headers*. These beams are covered by the fascia, which in the example above is coffered paneling.